# How to send a POST-Request to a web server containing a JSON-Object

Tags: json, post

I want to send a POST-Request to a web server containing a JSON-Object and also receive a response, also containing a JSON-Object for my coding class in high school , but I don't know how to do it or what program to use. I would appreciate any help. Also I use a Mac, not a PC

Comment: My advice would be to install the postman-plugin in your browser and try to send the request from there. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Read first, how to ask question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask